# Dagger Sign in Diogenes dictionary

Tags: dictionary

Can somebody explain what does this Dagger Sign mean in Diogenes presenting dictionary entries from perseus word study tool?

[image]

Comment: What is the URL for this dictionary?

Comment: @Quidam It's Diogenes, the free viewer application for TLG databases https://d.iogen.es/d/index.html
https://github.com/pjheslin/diogenes/releases

Answer (score 2):

I've found in another dictionary for two of such words marks that they are reconstructed forms (*)

[image]

[image]